# How to have "col-md-6" div appear when hovering over list items in separate div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Here is the code i have on my HTML doc. I have been trying to get this hover action to work, i have only gotten it to work so far when the description is a child of the li tag, which is not what i want. I want the description to be shown as a separate div.

```
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn header-left" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="2s">
                    <h2>Services</h2>
                      <ul class="services-list flex">
<!--Hover this list item for description div to appear-->
                        <li  id="item-1" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s"><h5><a href="#">Lighting System Design</a></h5>
                          <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".1s" id="lightingDesign">

                        </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
<!--Description div i want to appear when hover on #item-1-->
                  <div class="col-md-6 header-left wow fadeIn" id="description-1">
                    <h4>Lighting System Design</h4>
                    <p>Determining the equipment and programing required that meet interior anenter code hered exterior lighting specifications.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the element you want to display isn't adjacent to or inside of the element you want to toggle, you can't use CSS, but you can use javascript. I changed the `href` attribute of the link to be the `id` of the element to toggle. You could also use a `data-*` attribute instead if you wanted to leave the `href` value alone or change it to something else.

```js
$('.services-list a').hover(function() {
  $($(this).attr('href')).stop().fadeToggle();
})
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn header-left" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="2s">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <ul class="services-list flex">
      <li id="item-1" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <h5><a href="#description-1">Lighting System Design</a></h5>
        <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".1s" id="lightingDesign">

      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Description div i want to appear when hover on #item-1-->
    <div class="description col-md-6 header-left wow fadeIn" id="description-1">
      <h4>Lighting System Design</h4>
      <p>Determining the equipment and programing required that meet interior anenter code hered exterior lighting specifications.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using jQuery `mouseover` and `mouseleave` function. Check below snippet.

```js
$('#item-1').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('#description-1').fadeIn("fast");
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('#description-1').fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```css
#description-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn header-left" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="2s">
      <h2>Services</h2>
      <ul class="services-list flex">
        <!--Hover this list item for description div to appear-->
        <li id="item-1" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">
          <h5><a href="#">Lighting System Design</a></h5>
          <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".1s" id="lightingDesign"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Description div i want to appear when hover on #item-1-->
    <div class="col-md-6 header-left wow fadeIn" id="description-1">
      <h4>Lighting System Design</h4>
      <p>Determining the equipment and programing required that meet interior anenter code hered exterior lighting specifications.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```